# Is digital signal transmission different from square wave?

Tags: analog, signal, communication, signal-processing, digital-communications

I am just getting into signal processing and am having trouble understanding where generating square-waves by means of harmonics is useful.

Digital signal transmission can be achieved by changing voltage levels of transistors between high and low.  A good example is that of GPIO, easily being toggled between high and low (typically 5V and 0V).  If the receiver samples at the same rate, it can receive a message.

Where does the use of transmitting effectively the same type of information but by means of using many harmonics do generate the square waves arise? (If it does at all)

(In the above question, I assume they are effectively the same type of information being sent.  If this is incorrect, please explain)

Answer (score 1):

> where generating square-waves by means of harmonics is useful.

Nowhere.

Synthesis by adding sine waves is neat in academia. Once out of school, we generate waves in the most practical way. Specifically, if we want a square wave, we make one directly with a single square wave generator, we don't futs with 33 sine wave generators.

> the same type of information

A continuous square wave doesn't carry any information, not even 1 bit of information. (Oh, I suppose its frequency can be used as a reference.)

> Is digital signal transmission different from square wave?

Yes, because signal transmission has information and a continuous square wave doesn't.

Comment: `A continuous square wave doesn't carry any information` ... what about a heartbeat signal?

Comment: @jsotola One could argue it is zero because the entropy is zero i.e. the bit stream is perfectly predictable. That is, however, a data *rate* argument, and one could argue the frequency, amplitude, or precise harmonic distribution, are still "bits" of information (amount rather than rate).

Comment: Which is why I said; "Oh, I suppose its frequency can be used as a reference."

Answer (score 1):

Signals are rarely if ever generated by additive harmonics (as Andrea's answer says), but there are examples of communications methods that use sums of frequency bands.

The bands are usually evenly spaced (not harmonic), so as to make full use of the bandwidth available on the media (e.g. dubious quality DSL lines, over-the-air, etc.).  Each band might be treated independently, having some SNR and therefore maximum bitrate, determined by testing channel quality periodically; and the bit streams across all channels are split/combined at each end to make a complete wideband link, like a DSL or DOCSIS modem, or WiFi radio (to some extent), for example.

Note that the signals in each band are not sinusoidal, but having some modulation instead (usually an efficient and flexible scheme like QAM).

Note also that the GPIO communication you speak of (let's say async serial for example, having equally-timed bits), isn't a pure square wave.  You will find it helpful to think of signals in statistical terms: what is the chance a given bit/pulse is high or low?  If it's exactly alternating, that's a perfect 50% squarewave devoid of information.  *You can perfectly predict what the next bit will be.*

And if the bits aren't predictable, then the spectrum won't be a square wave with zero-width harmonics, but the harmonics are spread by the data pattern.  In general, a pseudorandom bit stream (PRBS) has a |sinc(f)| spectrum, basically because the spectrum of each individual bit (a rect(t) waveform) has a |sinc(f)| spectrum and the bits superimpose incoherently (not that they don't interfere, but that they randomly add and subtract, so that the overall magnitude ends up with this shape).  (A PRBS repeats eventually, so the spectrum -- integrated fully over that period -- will also be deterministic, composed of tones spaced at 1/period.  But this can be a very long time indeed, and so the spectrum looks like a random sampling of the probability distribution function (PDF), over more reasonable acquisition periods.)

Taking the Fourier transform of a random signal might not seem very meaningful just yet (or at all, if you haven't done transforms yet?).  But a proof of the above does exist.  And, basically, the randomness of the data corresponds to the uncertainty of frequency content, and this is why data is not transmitted with carriers and harmonics.  The interesting stuff happens around the carrier frequency(ies)!